# How to use the silverlight form validation?

Tags: silverlight

I need to creat some customer registration form and i need to check the validation of each line in the form.

What is the best way to do it ? ( i want to use Regular Expression )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You can use partial classes on the client side and add attributes provided in the ComponentModel namespace or you can write code to raise these events. WCF RIA services uses the attribute approach in the demos I've seen. RIA Services actually uses the same attributes to validate on the server and the client, which has good and bad points to it (in my opinion).

Here are some helpful links I've looked at in the past:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-binding-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx (he has a good start to create a base class to handle most of the INotifyDataErrorInfo functions in one place)

http://thejoyofcode.com/Silverlight_MVVM_and_Validation_Part_III.aspx
   http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/SL4BusinessModule3/SL4LOB_03_03_Validation/

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-and-asynchronous-validation-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx